# Belkin G Wireless Router to connect to Canon 495 wireless printer

Tags: wireless-networking

We have a Canon MP495 Series WiFi capable printer.  Instructions say to set it up as wireless requires a wireless accees point .  We have a Belkin G Wireless router we used at our house for internet a few years ago, and I don't even have the directions anymore.  We now have a Verizon wireless modem for our laptop that we use on the truck and I have no idea how to connect them all - or even the right questions to ask.  Would very much appreciate some guidance on it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Verizon wireless modem isnt a WiFi capable.  They are two different wireless technologies.

You arent completely out of luck, depending on how adventurous you are, there are options.  If your laptop supports WiFi, you can use [Internet Connection Sharing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing) to connect the printer to the laptop.

More than likely your printer has a USB port, the simplest thing to do would be connect it to your laptop with a USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your plan or business relationship with Verizon is like but, another option is to try and swap out those modems for one of the MiFi ["mobile hotspots"](http://www.verizonwireless.com/mobile-hotspots-1.shtml)